# tips when starting shell

Tags: macos, bash, shell, freebsd, tcsh

So one of the servers I am using has freebsd installed and it uses by default the tcsh shell. This has a pretty nice feature. Every time I log in via ssh it prints a tip. This called a lot my attention and I don't know if this exists for the bash shell and if so how to activate it.

Here is the last one I got:

```
FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE-p3 (GENERIC) #0: XXXXX

m5
Nice bash prompt: PS1='(\[$(tput md)\]\t <\w>\[$(tput me)\]) $(echo $?) \$ '
    -- Mathieu <mathieu@hal.interactionvirtuelle.com>
$
```

Comment: The `fortune` command can be configured to take tips from any file... Ubuntu packages `fortunes-ubuntu-server` and `fortunes-debian-hints` for some of this, they may be good starting points for you, though OS X is different enough that they won't all make sense...

Comment: thank you very much, if you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fortune command is not shell specific. It is generally called via rc at startup if it is configured. The fortune man(6) page describes several ways to call fortune with different files. Best of luck ;)